# read data from textfile in python and use in a function later

Tags: python, function, multiple-columns

Question: I want to read data from a textfile and use the data when called through a function. My code looks like:

```
f1 = open('file.dat', 'r')
for x in (raw.strip().split() for raw in f1):
    print x[0],x[1]

def cp(T):
     Tc=647.
     tau=Tc/T
     sum1 = 0.0
     n3=3.00632  
     for i in range(1,5):
            num1=((x[1]*tau)**2.)*math.exp(-x[1]*tau)
            den1=(1.-math.exp(-x[1]*tau))**2.
            sum1=sum1+((x[0]*num1)/den1)
     return Ra*(1.+n3+sum1)

**********************************************
Output:
0.97315 3.53734222
1.27950 7.74073708
0.96956 9.24437796
0.24873 27.5075105
```

However, I want to read this output line by line when called in function Cp(T) inside the for loop. For eg., when i=1, it should read x[0] as 0.97315 and y[0] as 3.53..and when i=2, it should read x[1]=1.27950 and y[1]=7.740737 and so on. I hope my question is clear.
Could someone please help how to call the data in the function?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if I fully understood your question, but I think you are looking for something along the lines of this?

```
def cp(T, filename):
    Tc = 647.
    tau = Tc / T
    sum1 = 0.0
    n3 = 3.00632

    results = []
    file = open(filename, 'r')
    for x in (raw.strip().split() for raw in file):
        num1 = ((x[1] * tau) ** 2.) * math.exp(-x[1] * tau)
        den1 = (1. - math.exp(-x[1] * tau)) ** 2.
        sum1 = sum1 + ((x[0] * num1) / den1)
        results.append(Ra * (1. + n3 + sum1))
    file.close()
return results

cp(T, 'file.dat')
```

Comment: Yes, I wanted to read my data line by line in the for x loop. But now I get this error: num1 = ((x[1] * tau) ** 2.) * math.exp(-x[1] * tau)
TypeError: only integer arrays with one element can be converted to an index

Comment: I know whats wrong. tau=Tc/T , here T is an array read from somewhere else. How to read T as one element (line by line) from its array.